# Environment problem with RStudio in Windows 10

Tags: r, windows-10, environment

I have been using R intensively for a number of years and consider myself fairly fluent in it (although admittedly still grappling with the concept of elegance in code). That being said, I am now having problems with it that I never had previously, and I think it may have something to do with either my new machine in particular, or Windows 10 itself. To explain, my work recently provided me with a more powerful computer, but that is running Windows 10, rather than the Windows 7 Professional that I had before.

As best I can figure, I can still use variables in the .GlobalEnv (following the function line-by-line) without issues, but if I try to run a process inside a function I have written, some variables that I create inside the function are randomly forgotten and it provides me with (for example) the error "Error in eval(parse(text=i)): object 'i' not found", even though 'i' was encoded by "for (i in vars)" in the previous line.

To top it all off, I have tested some of my older functions that use these processes routinely, and they are throwing errors on this machine that were nonexistent on my previous one.

Is this a compatibility issue with Windows 10? Might it have something to do with how the OS is splitting R processes among the threads? Does anyone have any idea?

I'll provide a snippet of code that is throwing the error. If someone else can replicate it, and can tell me where they think the bug is, I would be very grateful.

Thanks!

```
adonis.tbl <- function(dist, meta, vars){
  # where dist is a distance matrix of samples with distances based on 
  # community composition, meta is a table with metadata, 
  # and vars is a list of variables in meta, given as character strings
  # row.names in dist must match the corresponding sample names in meta, 
  # named 'SampleID' in the metadata table
  require(vegan)
  out <- data.frame()
  for (i in vars){
    ado <- adonis2(dist ~ eval(parse(text=i)),
                   data=meta[which(row.names(dist)%in%meta$SampleID),])
    out1 <- data.frame(R2=ado$R2[1], p=ado$`Pr(>F)`[1])
    out <- rbind(out, out1)
  }
  row.names(out) <- vars
  return(out)
}
```

In addition, here is some dummy code to reproduce the error with the above function.

```
dat <- matrix(runif(150, 1, 1000), 15, 10, dimnames=list(letters[1:15], LETTERS[6:15]))

tree <- ape::rtree(10, tip.label=LETTERS[6:15])

dist <- GUniFrac::GUniFrac(dat, tree, 0)

bdist <- dist$unifracs[,,2]

meta <- data.frame(SampleID=letters[1:15], 
                   var1=round(runif(15, 1, 5000)), 
                   var2=round(runif(15, 1, 1000)), 
                   var3=round(runif(15, 1, 500)))

test <- adonis.tbl(bdist, meta, c("var1", "var2", "var3"))
```

Comment: Without testing your code, maybe `get(i)` instead of `eval/parse`.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but nope. Same error.

Comment: Have you compared what was running on the windows 10 and windows 7 machine? is it same R version?  do sessionInfo() on both machines and compare

Comment: `fmla <- paste("dist", i, sep = "~"); fmla <- as.formula(fmla); ado <- adonis2(fmla, etc)`.

Comment: Also, what type of object is `dist`? Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(x)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(x, 20))` where `x` is each of the objects `dist`, `meta` and `vars`.

Comment: @CarlosSantillan, no, the Windows 10 is running 3.5.1 and Windows 7 was running 3.4.3. I've now tested the above code on both machines, and Windows 7 is giving me the same error. So I guess it's something wrong with the code itself, and I'm just totally blind to it..

Comment: @RuiBarradas {dist} is classed as 'matrix', rather than a true dist. It's still too big, even with a head list of 20 (the matrix is 531x531). But I can provide some dummy code.

Comment: silly as it may sound .. have you tried to rename the variable (instead of "i" call it "I" or "i2" something different), I have seen instances where an internal variable is being hidden by an external variable

Comment: Yeah, I tried that a few different ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't say *why* the problem is happening without a lot more work, but there's almost always a more robust solution that `eval(parse(...))`.  In this case `reformulate()` seems to work (I took the apparently redundant `which()` out of the next line, but that's unrelated):

```
ado <- adonis2(reformulate(i,response="dist"),
               data=meta[row.names(dist)%in%meta$SampleID,])
```

I get `NA`/`NaN` results, but I assume that's because the sample data set here is trivial.

Comment: Oh wonderful! Thank you so much, that would have never occurred to me in a million years. I'm going to skim through my older code and fix that with your suggestion too.
I really appreciate everyone's input!

Comment: if the answer solved your problem you're encouraged to click the check-mark to accept it ...